# React: How to update parent component's useEffect hook when using routes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-lifecycle

I use the `useEffect` hook to dispatch the `getQuestions` function in order to get the data from the server

```
function App () {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getQuestions());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <Routes>
            <Route exact path="/" element={<Layout/>}>
                <Route path="repetition" element={<Repetition/>}/>
                <Route path="family" element={<Family/>}/>
            </Route>
        </Routes>
    );
}
```

The problem is that when I, for example, open the `family` link (which I declared in the App function), initially I get the data, but when I refresh the page, the data disappears.

I certainly understand that when the page is refreshed the parent App component is not rendered from this and I get an error, similar issues I have looked at in the forums where it was suggested to use `withRouter` which updates the parent component, but my version of `react-router-dom` does not supports `withRouter`, except that I don't want to downgrade my version of `react-router-dom` to use `withRouter`.

I would like to know if there is any way to fix this problem.

Comment: Maybe you can consider storing your state in a context.

Comment: Have you tried removing dispatch from useEffect hook?

Comment: why not move data fetching part to family component

Comment: Thanks for the question @Fallen!  I thought about it, but here, in my subjective opinion, there is one problem, at the moment I have 5 child elements and I will have to declare useEffect in each child element, of course I don’t know for sure, but I don’t think this is the best option

Comment: @Synchro, each child component should require different type of data and making it a single request will not only be resource heavy but will also contain which might not even be put to use. So, i believe making 5 different request is appropriate but still it's only my opinion it might not apply to your case.

Comment: @Fallen I'll try your suggestion now. I originally thought of creating a large object with child arrays. Then I wanted to get a specific array in a specific child I'll try your, suggestion then test it in Google LightHouse and let you know later

Comment: @junwen-k Thanks for the interesting suggestion, I tried to save the data in the context but unfortunately it did not help

Answer (score 0):

I tried the option that @Fallen suggested, i.e. I applied the `useEffect` hook in each child element and analyzed this approach in **GoogleLighthouse**, and I'm happy with the results.

Here is my final code in child component

```
function Family () {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const questions = useSelector(state => state.QuestionsSlices.familyQuestions);

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(getFamilyQuestions());
    }, [dispatch]);

    return (
        <>
            {questions.data.map((item, idx) => (
                <div key={idx}>
                    { idx + 1 === questions.score && CheckQuestionsType(item, questions) }
                </div>
            ))}
        </>
    );
}
```